# How does React Create App create the build, connect the build, and how can it support multiple build files?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I have a current web site that is generates multiple builds via regular Visual Studio (not VS Code).

We essentially do:

```
module.exports = {
    context: __dirname + "/Scripts",
    entry: {
        build1: './Layout/functionality1.jsx',
        build2: './Layout/functionality2.jsx',
        ...
    },
...
```

then, for a specific index.cshtml file I include:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/Build/build1.js")"></script>
```

This works fine, but the downside is using webpack to build every time between dev cycles. I've been playing around with Create React App via Visual Studio Code (NOT regular Visual Stuido), and it uses using npm start to create the builds. Similarly, when updating and saving the App.js file that comes with Create React App, it automatically updates the localhost. This is absolutely terrific.

I want to implement this for my current website, but when looking into how create react app gets the app.js file into our html it is making way less sense to me. No where inside of the index.html file do we call any sort of build.js. In fact, I can not find a reference to the js files anywhere in this html file.

Where and how are these files getting linked to create react app? where is the html calling the js? index.html has no reference at all.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <!--
...
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
...
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

But I can see where index.js makes the reference to the root element in index.html.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

If I understand how this is happening, them I am under the impression that I can then figure out how to get three different main files hooked up to this Visual Studio Code Project to then use my previous build files essentially like so

http://localhost:3000/functionality1

http://localhost:3000/functionality2

http://localhost:3000/functionality3 ...

Edit:

here is my config file:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Chrome",
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/src",
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack:///src/*": "${webRoot}/*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: did you run `npm run build` ? the script tag and the js files are in the `build` folder. example from index.html: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.ebe34c76.js"></script>`

Comment: no, but that's part of my point. How is create-react-app loading this in without a build? That's what I'm trying to understand.

Comment: it uses html webpack plugin https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin

Comment: i would recommend creating a test app with create-react-app and ejecting it to see what it's doing under the hood. just keep in mind you can't go back after ejecting, that's why i recommend doing it on a test app